# Require Signed DLL Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

I am working on one project where I needed to create Library folder for windows7.
I have gone through msdn article to create one.
What I found is, the DLL is not signed version. so the project I want to run is required signed DLL.

I have tried to make DLL strong name and atteched strong key buy given [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/341645/Referenced-assembly-does-not-have-a-strong-name).

Buy I am getting error like 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044 - Strong name is required in one of it's dependancies'. any solutions that strikes in your mind to do this?

I've tried to create a separate DLL and attached it with my project but it gives me the same error when I execute this statement.

```
ShellLibrary lib = new ShellLibrary("Library Name", true);
```

Please provide your inputs.

Answer (score 4):

Where did you get the DLL from?

I had the same issue and had originally installed [this version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/) of the NuGet package for the library (which unfortunately in Visual Studio gives the impression it is packaged by Microsoft, when it actually isn't).

I installed the following alternative package from NuGet, and this one has been strong-named:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell/

Try using that package and see if your errors are resolved.

Comment: This is an issue with the official Microsoft package too. (The one that literally says By Microsoft)